# Is landing time displayed in local timezone?

Tags: air-travel, timezones

From my understanding:

- Take off is in timezone of airport of departure.
- Landing is in timezone of airport of arrival.

I fly from Munich at 21:50, and I arrive in Athens at 01:10.

So, I will land in Athens at 01:10. Correct?

Comment: It depends on what "01:10" mean to you.

Comment: If it was in timezone of Hellas or timezone of Germany @el.pescado. Both answers, answer my question, thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing this at the airport, or online?  Because online, they'll often list each time in the time zone of the airport it's talking about.  I've never paid enough attention to it while at airports.

Comment: @Joe in my booking's flight details, online.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Flight time between the two cities is approximately [2 hours 25 minutes](https://www.prokerala.com/travel/flight-time/from-athens/to-munich/). If the landing timezone was the same as Munich, it would land at around 00:10.

Since the ETA is 01:10 and we know that the time difference between these 2 places is 1 hour (Munich = UTC+1, Athens = UTC+2), it is safe to say that **Yes you will land at 01:10 local time in Athens.**

This is generally the practice everywhere. Take-off  and landing times are almost always displayed in local timezones at the respective airports. I can't seem to find a counter-example so far.

Comment: I think the only other alternative would be to have times in UTC, but most definitely, on customer-facing info, it's always local time.

Comment: Maybe there are airports in locations where the de facto and de jure timezone diverge?  I remember being confused by the time in far western Texas, and a colleague in Eureka, Nunavut reported that Google and Wikipedia not only disagreed with each other about the local time, but that they were both wrong, too. Also, Russian railways used to display all times nationwide in Moscow time, maybe they used to do the same with flights?

Comment: Yes it’s quite possible. That’s why I didn’t make a blanket statement that it is always the case :D

Comment: You could add that usually, when you buy a ticket, the site does not only show you the departure and arrival times, but also the total duration (they do it because it comes in handy if you are flying across several time zones, or if you have layovers). So in general there's no need to find an external website that estimates the flight's duration, as you had to do in this case.

Comment: @gerrit The far-west tip of Texas (I believe the only airport there is in El Paso) is in Mountain Time, no "de facto" about it.

Comment: Even Russia (where Moscow time is used for train and ship arrival / departure times regardless of timezone) uses the Local Timezone for plane arrival / departure.

Comment: @gerrit Timekeeping is a man made construct, there is no such thing as de facto time, especially for things related to timezones.

Comment: @LieRyan What I would understand by "de-facto time" is officially called "local solar time". I think what gerrit means is that some territories are disputed (Abkhazia, Transnistria, the Halai'ib Triangle, West Bank, Formosa, West Sahara, Molvania, Antarctica and others), and if some had changed time zone during the dispute (they didn't), their international airports (there aren't any) would have been caught between a rock and a hard place w.r.t. "local" time.

Comment: @Alexander: you don't need to go to disputed countries to get local "de facto" time confusion. China, India, and Greenland for example, runs on a single timezone, despite spanning an area that should've covered multiple. None of their territories are disputed (well... let's not get into that debate).

Comment: This answer is unclear. Is 2 hours and 25 minutes the gate-to-gate time, or the flight time? They are very different things.

Comment: @chrylis Except that ["Northwestern Culberson County near Guadalupe Mountains National Park unofficially observes Mountain Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Texas), which for a traveller who doesn't know where the northwest of those counties start and end, can be confusing.

Comment: @LieRyan Of course it's a man made difference.  If the locals all use a different time than whatever the official time the relevant authorities have set, then the de facto time and the de jure time differ.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. The time displayed is always the airport local time.